# Cannot add select value to input component laravel

Tags: laravel, forms, html-select

I have the following code in my `blade file`

```
 @include('component.select',[
      'label' => 'State',
      'name' => 'state',
      'placeholder' => 'Select State',
      'class' => '',
      'data'=> $states,
      'errorMessage' => "required",
      'value' => $prop->state
  ])
```

You can see that i added the `value` at the bottom but it does not  select the value in the drop down when i view the page.

Here is the prior developers component

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>{{ $label }}</label>
    <select class="select-area form-control {{ !empty($class) ? $class : '' }}" name="{{ $name }}" data-placeholder="{{ $placeholder }}">
        @foreach($data as $d)

            <option value="{{ $d['id'] }}" @if(old($name) == $d['id'] ) selected @endif>
                {{ $d['text'] }}
            </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: we dont know your `component.select` view...

Comment: added to qustion

Comment: i dont see the `$value` parameter in the view. You might want to replace `old($name)` with `$value`, or combine the two together so form submission state can also be taken into account.